# Primeira pergunta de novo usuário não aparece na linha de análise

Tags: suporte, status-intencional

Já tinha reparado isso, porque algumas vezes editei uma pergunta de um novo usuário fora da linha de análise, e imaginei que seria sempre melhor fazer pela linha (pensando no processo de tarefas), então comecei a ir procurar na linha e não achar, e acabava editando fora da linha mesmo.

Então hoje, pra ter certeza, fui no [perfil do usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/24655/jos%C3%A9-marcello-lopes) que fez a pergunta e é realmente [a primeira dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/24655/jos%C3%A9-marcello-lopes?tab=questions), e [até este momento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) não está aparecendo.

Além desta informação tenho uma pergunta: Quando eu edito o post de um primeiro usuário fora da linha de análise isso entra como tarefa cumprida em primeiras publicações?

**Nota: Acabei de atualizar aqui e apareceu. :-)** (acho que tem um pequeno lag né, mas vou deixar pela pergunta)

Comment: As perguntas não vão para a fila (gostei de "linha") de análise imediatamente, só depois de alguns minutos (mas não sei quantos).

Comment: @bfavaretto convinha saber quantos.

Comment: @JorgeB. não tenho certeza se de repente não existe um algoritmo que determina quantos minutos são dependendo de outros fatores

Comment: @JorgeB. Acabei de monitorar esta pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62670/recuperar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-certificado-digital e levou 10 minutos (talvez exatamente) para aparecer na **fila**.

Comment: @Math e gustavox de qualquer forma era bom saber ao certo...

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, seria legal saber ao certo, mas tenho quaaase :-) certeza de que são 10 minutos redondos. Btw, eu também queria saber se as edições que faço em primeiras publicações (ou quando voto pelo fechamento ou reabertura) **fora da fila de análise** entram como tarefa cumprida.